# Which polyhedron has 17 vertices, 34 edges and 19 faces?

Tags: graph-theory, polyhedra

on exam I had task to check that there is polyhedron with 8 triangle faces, 11 quadrangle, each vertices have degree 4. after calculate I obtain that it have 34 edges, 17 vertices and 19 faces but i don't know how to drow it. any ideas? or maybe anyone know online generator for pylohendron. wolfram alfa unfortunately doesn't work for very specific polyhendrons.

Comment: Drawing/visualizing such a polyhedron?  I have trouble drawing tetrahedrons!  haha.  Or are you asking about the polyhedral graph?

Comment: no, i asking about polyhedron, because one part of task was to draw a polyhendron if it exist.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the graph of such a polyhedron:

[image]

The bluish regions (including the outer region) are quadrangles, and the reddish ones are triangles. As you can see, it meets the given requirements.

I only found this through trial and error and a certain amount of luck. It doesn't seem realistic to me to find such an object on an exam (let alone draw the corresponding polyhedron in 3d?!—surely the graph is enough) unless there is some context we are missing.

---

EDIT: redrew graph to make it 4-regular.

Comment: Oooh. Contact graphs. I just did a project on them regarding sphere packings. Good times.

Comment: Your graph is not 4-regular. There are two vertices of degree 5.

Comment: @PerryIverson Oh no! Thanks for pointing that out. Back to the drawing board $\ldots$

Comment: $\ldots$ and in fact I see that there are three vertices of degree 5, and three of degree 3.

Comment: @PerryIverson I've redrawn the graph; this should work. I started from the original graph and just changed a few edges around.

Comment: +1 - I'm impressed. I doodled for a bit and couldn't seem to make it work. I wonder if there's a general method for constructing these, and if all polyhedra with similar constraints (consistent with Euler's formula) are constructible?

Comment: @PerryIverson I was wondering the same. Although in this case I just played around until I found the right graph, I think a more systematic approach would be to start with a simple graph then apply transformations that preserve some feature, say 4-regularity. For instance, picture a square flanked by two triangles, with additional outer edges so that all vertices have degree 4. Now remove the two inner edges and add diagonals across the former square; now there are two squares and two triangles, and one extra vertex. So, overall, this operation adds 1 square and 1 vertex.